# How to highlight comments in WordPress admin panel?

Tags: wordpress, admin, highlight

I want to highlight author comments in admin panel of WordPress engine. I have many comments on my blog every day, and it's hard sometimes in admin panel to find my own comment.

Comment: Thanks, one more question, is it possible to highlight new comments also?

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with a targeted action hook and a bit of CSS:

```
add_action( 'admin_head-edit-comments.php', 'colored_comments_so_15232115' );

function colored_comments_so_15232115()
{
    ?>
    <style>.comment-author-USER_LOGIN { background-color: #DFDB83 }</style>
    <?php
}
```

Replace `USER_LOGIN` with your login name. And surely, you could add as many users/background-colors as needed.

This CSS is only printed in the Comments page (`/wp-admin/edit-comments.php`) by using the hook [`admin_head-$hook_suffix`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-admin/admin-header.php#L68).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a plugin: [Comment Moderation Highlights](https://wordpress.org/plugins/comment-moderation-highlights/)

note: I'm the plugin developer.

Set it so that it looks for your email addresss, pick a color and save. All your comments will be Highlighted within the comments admin.